# Why dont I have run icon next to class in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, .class-file

I can run java classes on intellij only by right clicking. I dont have run icon on left side of the class and @Test. My java class files are also  not .class but .java files all the time, even when I run them. Moreover, I dont get any warning, error or red line when classes are not imported. After I run, it gives me error on the console saying "Error(6,6) java: cannot find symbol". How can i fix this issue? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Seems like a compiler error. Can you show your code and ehere exactly the error occurs?

Comment: Can you right-click the folder containing your code, go to "Mark Directory As" and have the option to "Mark as Sources Root"?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly source code are always in .java file and File with .class are compiled class used by the JVM and you shouldn't have to use it.

Maybe you should add a screen to your question because

`Error(6,6) java: cannot find symbol`

is a little too generics.

But you should test if your library are correctly setup.